# How do I order a dataframe by a vector of column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
v <- data.frame(a=c(12,45,23), b=c(34,23,11))
```

I also have a vector of columns I would like to sort by as:

```
s <- c("a", "b")
```

How do I sort `v` using `s`?

> NOTE: Essentially this is what I would like to get working but it
>   doesn't work:

```
v[order(s),]
```

So I would expect the following:

```
a  b
12 34
23 11
45 23
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subset the dataset with the `s` `vector` and if there are multiple columns, then pass the function `order` in `do.call` to order the rows of the dataset

```
v[do.call(order, v[s]),]
```

Comment: should have known: when in doubt - do.call()

Answer (score 4):

If using `dplyr`:

```
arrange_at(v,s)
```